# This must be simple - ASP Global Variable

Tags: asp.net

Ok, I've been stuck on this for a while now and it must be so simple. Cant find exact answr via google but it must be there.

I'm new to Web Apps (reasonably new to dev).

I have a web form with a text box on and a button - very simples.. On button_click, this calls multiple methods from other classes, in these other classes, I need to know the value of the text that was entered in the textbox. I could pass this value around with each new class instantiation - is this the only way to do it? or how can I create a global variable that the other classes can just access 
(i.e. string test = _default.mystring)

I cant create a static property. I'm sure this is something rather basic but cant seem to get my gead around it.

thanks

Comment: It is not totally clear to me, what you are willing to do. You want to use the textbox entry in other classes? Can you give an example of those?

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing is pass the value as parameter to the function of other class

or

make use of session variable to gain access.

Answer (score 0):

The "correct" way to do this would be to pass the string around as arguments to the methods that need it - either in the constructor of objects, or (more commonly practiced) as parameters to the methods where it's needed.

There is no way to create a global variable without creating a static property on some class (the class can also be static), since .NET is inherently object oriented, and there is no .NET code that isn't contained in a class.

Answer (score 0):

A property should work fine:

```
private static string _text;

public static string Text
{
 get {return _text;}
 set {text = value;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store user specific data in session variables and application specific data in application variables. You can access these variables on every page of your application
`Session["key"]="value";`

`Application["key"]="value";`

On accessing variables type cast the variable to the exact data type.
IF Session contains integer value.

`Session["1"]=34;
int a = int.Parse(Session["1"].ToString());`